# MATLAB syms error

Tags: matlab, function, symbols, equation

I have two root. `Er1` and `Er2`. `Er1 = Er1r+(Er1i)*i` and `Er2 = Er2r+(Er2i)*i`. So they are complex.

```
syms Er1r Er1i Er2r Er2i real

Er1 = Er1r+(Er1i)*i
Er2 = Er2r+(Er2i)*i
Er  = [Er1,Er2]

h = 0.0001

Er111 = (Er1r+h)+(Er1i)*i
Er112 = (Er1r-h)+(Er1i)*i
Er121 = (Er1r)+(Er1i+h)*i
Er122 = (Er1r)+(Er1i-h)*i

Er211 = (Er2r+h)+(Er2i)*i
Er212 = (Er2r-h)+(Er2i)*i
Er221 = (Er2r)+(Er2i+h)*i
Er222 = (Er2r)+(Er2i-h)*i

eqn1(Er) = 3*Er111^2+5*Er111+Er111
eqn2(Er) = 7*Er112^2-4*Er112+2*Er112
.
.
.
eqn8(Er) = 3*Er222^2+9*Er222-4*Er222
```

I want to write 8 equations. But they are function. So Er is symbol. I have error. How can I fix?

Error message;

```
Error using sym/subsindex (line 766)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the arguments are symbolic variables and the body of
the function is a SYM expression. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical, or ':'.

Error in sym/privsubsasgn (line 1031)
                L_tilde2 = builtin('subsasgn',L_tilde,struct('type','()','subs',{varargin}),R_tilde);

Error in sym/subsasgn (line 868)
            C = privsubsasgn(L,R,inds{:});

Error in m0708_2 (line 63)
eqn1(Er) = 3*Er111^2+5*Er111+Er111
```

Comment: Where did you find this syntax `eqn1(Er) = 3*Er111^2+5*Er111+Er111`? What do you mean by e.g. `eqn1(Er)`? The 1st equation is a function of `Er111` and not of `Er`... Just remove the `(Er)` from the definition of `eqn1...8`. Also it might help if you provide an image of the equation system that you're trying to solve - maybe you shouldn't be solving it with `syms` at all...

Comment: I need function. I need use (Er). Because Er is not defined. It is variable.

Comment: How is this not a definition of `Er`: `Er  = [Er1,Er2]` ?

Comment: Yes, it is definition but `Er`` is variable. The value is not clear.